# EXC_BAD_ACCESS, when accessing the object pointed by the vector of pointers

Tags: c++, unix, stl, vector, exc-bad-access

I have a vector of pointers..

I want to access my Image object via the pointer stored in the std::vector. After the iterator finds my object, I want to access/modify certain members of the Image object being pointed by the pointer in a vector.

Please help !!

---

```
class Image;
typedef std::vector <Image*> VecImages;
typedef VecImages::iterator ImagesIter;

class My_Images
{
        private:
            VecImages m_Images;

        public:
            My_Images() {}
            ~My_Images();

            void addImage(Image* img) {m_Images.push_back(img);}
            Image* getImage(string& rID);
};

// get image method
Image* My_Images::getImage(string& rID)
{
    ImagesIter foundImg = m_Images.begin();

    while (foundImg != m_Images.end()) {
        Image* img = *foundImg;      ***<<<<----------- [EXC_BAD_ACCESS is reported here]***
        const string &strID = img->get_strRId();
        if (strID == rID) {
            return (*foundImg);
        }
        ++foundImg;
    }

    return NULL;
}

// get-id method
const string& Image::get_strRId(void) {return m_strRId;}

// copy constructor
Image::Image(const Image& _src)
    :   m_strRId(_src.m_strRId)
{}
```

I have another class named builder ... and there I'm invoking the addImage() method like this ...
         My_Images *m_images; (I create this 'new')
         Image *currImg = new Image;
         currImg->setName("ABC"); ... and several other 'set' functions are called on currImg (mainly setting std::string's).

And then I add it into the vector using following call.

m_images->addImage(currImg);

And once this is stored in the vector, I giveup it's ownership.
  currImg = NULL;

---

```
template <class _Type>
_Type* ChAutoPtr<_Type>::giveUpOwnership()
{
#ifdef VERIFY_WITH_SHADOW_STACK
    // Check to see if the last auto-ptr is the one that is being
    // given up!!!
    if (m_pInstance != NULL)
    {
        void* pTop = g_cleanupStackShadow.top();
        ChASSERT(pTop == m_pInstance);
        g_cleanupStackShadow.pop();
    }
#endif /* _DEBUG */

    _Type* pTmp = m_pInstance;
    m_pInstance = NULL;
    return pTmp;
}
```

Comment: What are you passing to `addImage`? Show how you're using it.

Comment: I have another class named builder ... and there I'm invoking the addImage() method like this ...
         My_Images *m_images; (I create this 'new')
         Image *currImg = new Image;
         currImg->setName("ABC"); ... and several other 'set' functions are called on currImg (mainly setting std::string's).

And then I add it into the vector using following call.

  m_images->addImage(currImg);

And once this is stored in the vector, I giveup it's ownership.
  currImg = NULL;

Answer (score 2):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS means that you either (1) added uninitialized object to the vector or (2) its life was short and it ceased to exist prior the invocation of getImage(). You may try to enable NSZombies or verify the life span and scope of images added to the vector. Preferably, try using smart pointers (e.g. shared_ptr).

Comment: In fact, I am using smart pointers. And giving up ownership when handing it over to addImage() call. (The vector is of raw pointers and not the smart pointers).

Comment: @DeepakPawar: The code you posted doesn't use smart pointers. Please post the actual code you're using, not two completely different descriptions of it.

Comment: please post the code where you give up the ownership and what class of SP you use.

Comment: Alright .. here it is .. we have written a wrapper on top of the smart pointers, hence in order not to complicate things, did not post the code earlier... updated the post with the code.

Comment: I got a work-around to my problem. Having the Image object inside an auto_ptr was the issue. It was adding (handing-over) the Image to the vector properly, but by the time I came back to the vector to access that Image, the object was already getting deleted from there. And the invalid or deleted object access was causing the EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Instead I used a raw pointer, and then added that to the vector. And that solved the problem..... But I am not sure what was exactly the problem with using auto_ptr and handing it over to the vector. Anyone with any help or guess?. Thank you.